# golang make 0 length slice and re-slicing slice not as expected

Tags: go, slice

I saw this code feel confusing，please help me explain.

the code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := make([]int, 0, 10)
    s1 := s[0:1]
    s1[0] = 1
    println("-----")
    fmt.Println(s1, len(s1), cap(s1)) //[1] 1 10
    fmt.Println(s, len(s), cap(s))    //[] 0 10
    fmt.Println(s, s[0:10])           // [] [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
}
```

The above program can be executed perfectly，While print value is not meet my expectations，I have two questions:

- why s1 print value is: [1], while s print value is [] in the `fmt.Println(s1, len(s1), cap(s1))` and `fmt.Println(s, len(s), cap(s))`. I think s1 value is equal to s value is [1].
- why s[0:10] may print [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], while s print []. I think s[0:10] is re-slice of s，if s is [], s[0:10] is [] too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `s1` prints `[1]` because it is a slice of length 1, and it has the element 1 within that length. It is length 1 because it is a slice of `s` from `0` to `1`. Hence, `s1 := s[0:1]`
- `s` prints the value `[]` because it is a slice of length 0. There are no values to show when the length is 0, so there is nothing between the brackets. It is length 0 because it was specified as such in the `make` call. When using `make` to make a slice, the second argument is the length of the slice.
- `s[0:10]` may print `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` because it is allowed to re-slice an existing slice into its whole underlying capacity, not just the length. Since the re-slice goes from `0` to `10`, it will include 10 values (the second bound of the slice is non-inclusive). That's why you see all 10 values in the printout.
- As a bonus point, `s[0:10]` cannot be `[]` because that would mean you specify a slice of length 10 and get in return a slice of length 0. In Go, the length of a slice `s[a:b]` will always have a length of `b - a`. If that's not possible, then the program will panic. It will not give you a slice of some other length. See the explanation of these rules in the language specification: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions